# Baidu push notification channel id is not generated on one plus 3 phone with oxygen os 4.1.7 and android V7.1.1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, baidu

OnePlusAppBootManager: #skipBroadcast # black action : Intent { act=com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.RECEIVE flg=0x30 pkg=com.equationswork.kinghoo cmp=com.equationswork.kinghoo/com.cordova.plugins.push.baidu.BaiduPushReceiver (has extras) }

I got this error in android studio Logcat please help me to get out from this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a code issue, this error occurred due to operating system changes you need to follow following steps to resolve this issue: 1. Go to settings > Battery and tap the ellipses in the upper right corner.Then disable aggressive Doze and App hibernation. 2. Open the affected app, then trigger the app switcher and lock the app by tapping lock icon beside it. 3. Go to settings>App>Gear Icon, Then enable App auto lunch.